# How to check if your join result is correct? (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table with millions of rows, and another table with 100K+ rows. I want to perform inner join using these two table using Python/Pandas. How do I check if my join result is correct?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Wrong link.Does my answer solved your problem?

Comment: yeah, thanks so much~